# How do I know my process's scheduling policy on Linux?

Tags: linux

I know RR FIFO scheduling policy.

but is there a way to write a **C program** on Linux to know the current process's scheduling policy?

Comment: You want to scheduling C program or the program already scheduled just to know when it was ran?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`sched_getscheduler(2)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_getscheduler.2.html):

> **`sched_getscheduler()`** returns the current scheduling policy of the thread identified by *pid*.  If *pid* equals zero, the policy of the calling thread will be retrieved.